# BoostBuild: patchlevel.h does not exist

Tags: python, boost, boost-build

I'm trying to compile a C++ project using bjam on Ubuntu 11.04. I keep getting the following error:

```
../../libraries/boost_1_44_0/boost/python/detail/wrap_python.hpp:75:24: fatal error: patchlevel.h: No such file or directory
```

I searched my project directory and there are several files named patchlevel.h but I don't know what they are. Are they part of Boost?

I also get this error several times:

```
pa-vision-lib/../captureformat.h:4:25: fatal error: linux/ovcam.h: No such file or directory
```

This file also definitely exists. Is there a path setting of some sort in any of the Boost config files that I need to change to point to these files?

Comment: How did you build Boost.Python? Did you configure Boost.Build properly for your Python installation as outlined [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/python/doc/building.html#configuring-boost-build)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

IIRC patchlevel.h is a python-dev header, check this package is installed (i dont remember the exact name but it si the C header for python binding).

ovcam.h is not part of boost in anyway.

Comment: I just checked and I do have python-dev installed. Also, ovcam I know is a part of my project but I don't know why boost can't find it.

Comment: Ah, I finally realized I needed to install the python-dev2.6 package. I'm cross-compiling for python2.6 so I needed the older package.

Answer (score 7):

For Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS, please try:

> apt-get install python-dev