# Converted python code to C using cython windows

Tags: windows, cython, python-3.5

My program is "Hello World". If I try to compile the C code I get this error:

> Unable to open include file `patchlevel.h`

How to fix this?
My Python version 3.5.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6782071/boostbuild-patchlevel-h-does-not-exist

Comment: I checked that question already. Python-dev is for linux machine. For windows there is no pythondev?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16448710/how-to-get-python-dev-for-windows

Comment: Already read that and this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23995129/how-can-i-manage-to-install-packages-within-python-dev-on-windows-systems-just-l

Comment: I can see the path for include files by the way i fixed python.h file whereas, patchlevel.h not taking.

Comment: Right. Does this file `patchlevel.h` exist in the `include` folder?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16448710/how-to-get-python-dev-for-windows

Comment: He fixed it Meet Taraviya. I didn't understand how the way he fixed?
python-config --ldflags